# Open files in background on MacOS Sierra?

Tags: finder, automator, ebook

I often want to open several files, and then check through them. They may not appear consecutively in Finder or Calibre, so I have to select a few, open them, select more, open them, etc.

Unfortunately, my reading apps take focus as these open, so I have to fight my way back to the Finder or Calibre to select more, open them, etc.

So it would be very helpful to be able to open these in the background, and then go to the reading app when they're done. I saw a previous suggestion to open applications in the background, and tried it as an application and as a service, but couldn't get it to work, even trying different terms such as -ga Clearview instead of --hide.

[Open applications in the background in OS X, I don't want my focus taken from me. Respect my Focus!](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/233981/open-applications-in-the-background-in-os-x-i-dont-want-my-focus-taken-from-me)

Any other options?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to go back to Finder you just need to open Script Editor and paste this code:

```
repeat
    if "Finder" is not frontmost application then
        tell application "Finder"
            activate
        end tell
    end if
end repeat
```

Save it as an application, like FinderAlwaysON and execute it before starting your work.

[image]

Be aware that this will lock your computer with Finder, so when your are done opening the files bring up Force Quit (Command+Option+ESC) and close the app.

[image]